# How to solve the monkey issue like this?

Tags: android, monkey

We use monkey to verify the Contacts app, it shows fail log:

```
08-14 19:11:08.948 W/dalvikvm( 1142): threadid=2: spin on suspend #4 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142): "GC" daemon prio=5 tid=2 RUNNABLE
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4131af20 self=0x1e2518
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   | sysTid=1143 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1529440
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   | schedstat=( 310000000 30000000 106 ) utm=28 stm=3 core=1
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142): 
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a3d460 self=0x12800
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   | sysTid=1142 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1074345096
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   | schedstat=( 1390000000 150000000 476 ) utm=121 stm=18 core=2
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at com.android.contacts.dialpad.DialpadFragment.onResume(DialpadFragment.java:~693)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:873)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:437)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:804)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1016)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-14 19:11:08.948 I/dalvikvm( 1142):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have never seen the stack trace like above, it seems like that triggered by dalvic VM, anybody can tell me some details? Thanks very much!